# Get JSON Data for editing in a Modal using Data Table JQuery

Tags: php, html, jquery, json, ajax

I am making a Dashboard for my portfolio Website which builing with php,OOP,ajax and Jquery datatable. For grabbing data I use datatable. I can show the data into table. But I can not figure out that How to grab single data from data table into a bootstrap modal when i click on edit button? I have tried many tutorial from YouTube and google. json data shows in the devtool. But not in the modal. here is the screen shot of the problem along with my Dashboard class and table.js file
[data shown as json format but not shown in the modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMDm8.png)

This is my modal html code :

```
    <div id="recordModal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
    
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data- 
        dismiss="modal">&times;</button>                    
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                <form method="POST" id="recordForm" enctype="multipart/form- 
        data">
                <div class="table-responsive-sm">
                    <table class=" table table-borderless table-sm">   
                    <tr>
                    <td><label for="Image">Image:</label></td>
                    <td>
                    <input type="file" name="image"  class="form-control-file 
    form-control-sm" id="user_img">
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td> <label for="Name">Name:</label></td>
                             <td>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control-sm 
    form-control" id="user_name" name="Name"  placeholder="Enter your Name">
                            </td>
                         </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td> <label for="Title">Title:</label> </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control-sm 
    form-control" id="user_title" name="Title" placeholder="Enter a Title">
                            </td>
                        </tr>             
                        <tr>
                            <td> <label for="Aim & Mission">Mission:</label> 
    </td>
                            <td>
                                <textarea name="Vision" id="vision" cols="10" 
    rows="5" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Enter a 
     Description about you!!">
                                </textarea>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td> <label for="Expertise">Expertise in:</label> 
     </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control-sm 
    form-control" id="expt" name="Expertise" placeholder="Enter what you 
     expert 
    in!!">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label for="Experience">Experience:</label> 
   </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control-sm 
    form-control" id="exper" name="Experience" placeholder="Enter your 
   current 
    position!!">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td> <label for="Current Position:">Position:</label> 
    </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control-sm form- 
    control" id="cPos" name="cPosition" placeholder="Enter your Name">
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td> <label for="Link">Link Fiverr:</label></td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control-sm 
        form-control" id="fiver" name="Fiverr" placeholder="link of your 
    fiverr 
    profile">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="1"> <label for="Link">Link LinkedIn: 
   </label> </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control-sm 
         form-control" id="linked" name="linkedIn" placeholder="link of your 
        fiverr 
        profile">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td> <label for="Link">Link Upwork:</label></td>
                            <td>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control-sm 
         form-control" id="upwo" name="upWork" placeholder="link of your 
         fiverr 
         profile">
                            </td>
                        </tr>                       
                         
                    </table>
                </div>                  
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id">
                    <input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" value="">
                    <input type="submit" name="save" id="save" class="btn 
          btn-info" value="Save">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data- 
          dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        
        </div>

        </div>
     </div>
```

Here is my code of DashBoard class :

```
   <?php
 namespace PortFolioApp\Dashboard;
use PortFolioApp\helpers\Format;
 use PDO;
 use PortFolioApp\Model\Database;

    class DashBoard extends Database
    {

        public $id;
        public $name;
        public $title;
        public $vision;
        public $expertise;
        public $experience;
        public $cPosition;
        public $fiVer;
        public $upWork;
        public $linkedIn;
        public $image;
      

        public function setData($array)
        {
            if (array_key_exists("id", $array)) {
                $this->id = $array['id'];
            }
            if (array_key_exists("Name", $array)) {
                $this->name = $array['Name'];
            }
            if (array_key_exists("Title", $array)) {
                $this->title = $array['Title'];
            }

            if (array_key_exists("Vision", $array)) {
                $this->vision = $array['Vision'];
            }
            if (array_key_exists("Expertise", $array)) {
                $this->expertise = $array['Expertise'];
            }

            if (array_key_exists("Experience", $array)) {
                $this->experience = $array['Experience'];
            }

            if (array_key_exists("cPosition", $array)) {
                $this->cPosition = $array['cPosition'];
            }

            if (array_key_exists("Fiverr", $array)) {
                $this->fiVer = $array['Fiverr'];
            }
            if (array_key_exists("upWork", $array)) {
                $this->upWork = $array['upWork'];
            }

            if (array_key_exists("linkedIn", $array)) {
                $this->linkedIn = $array['linkedIn'];
            }
            if (array_key_exists("profilePicture", $array)) {
                $this->image = $array['profilePicture'];
            } }//end of setData;

        //starting data store function;

        public function store()
        {
            
            $name = $this->name;
            $title = $this->title;
            $vision = $this->vision;
            $cPosition = $this->cPosition;
            $expertise = $this->expertise;
            $experience = $this->experience;
            $fiVer = $this->fiVer;
            $upWork = $this->upWork;
            $linkedIn = $this->linkedIn;
            $image = $this->image;
    
          $array = array();
            $sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO 
            summary (name,
            title,
            vision,
            cposition,
            expertise,
            experience,
            fiverr,
            upwork,
            linkedin,
            profile)
             VALUES (:name,
             :title,
             :vision,
             :cPosition,
             :expertise,
             :experience,
             :fiVer,
             :upWork,
             :linkedIn,
             :image)";

            $dataArray = array(
                ':name' =>$name,
                ':title' =>$title,
                ':vision'=>$vision,
                ':cPosition'=>$cPosition,
                ':expertise'=>$expertise,
                ':experience'=>$experience,
                ':fiVer'=>$fiVer,
                ':upWork'=>$upWork,
                ':linkedIn'=>$linkedIn,
                ':image'=>$image
                );

$STH = $this->DBH->prepare($sqlQuery);
foreach($dataArray as $dt=>$key){
   $STH->bindValue(':'.$dt, $key,PDO::PARAM_STR);
}
 $result = $STH->execute($dataArray);
        //  return $STH->rowCount();
        
            if (isset($result)) {
               // $ok = false;
                   if (empty($dataArray[':name'])){
                   // $ok = true;
                      $array[] = "empty form  not submitted";
                  
                } else {
                  //  $ok = false;
                   $array[] ="<p class='alert alert-success'>form submitted</p>";
                } } 
          
            foreach($array as $ar)
                {
                    echo json_encode($ar);
                }  }

                //view all the data in front-end
        
       public function index()
        {
            $sqlQuery = "select * from summary WHERE is_trashed='NO'";
            $STH = $this->DBH->query($sqlQuery);
            $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $allData = $STH->fetchAll();
  
        return $allData;
       }
       
       //fetch data from database in a datatable
       public function fetch()
        {
 // $srQuery = '';
$draw = $_POST['draw'];
$row = $_POST['start'];
$rowperpage = $_POST['length']; // Rows display per page
$columnIndex = $_POST['order'][0]['column']; // Column index
$columnName = $_POST['columns'][$columnIndex]['data']; // Column name
$columnSortOrder = $_POST['order'][0]['dir']; // asc or desc
$searchValue = $_POST['search']['value']; // Search value

$searchArray = array();

$searchQuery = " ";
if($searchValue != ''){
   $searchQuery = "AND ( `name` LIKE :name or 
        `title` LIKE :title OR 
        `vision` LIKE :vision OR
         `expertise` LIKE :expertise OR
        `experience` LIKE :experience OR
        `cposition` LIKE :cposition OR
        `fiverr` LIKE :fiverr OR
        `upwork` LIKE :upwork OR
        `linkedin` LIKE :linkedin OR
        `profile` LIKE :profile 
        ) ";
    
   $searchArray = array( 
        'name'=>"% $searchValue %", 
        'title'=>"% $searchValue %",
        'vision'=>"% $searchValue %",
        'expertise'=>"% $searchValue %",
        'experience'=>"% $searchValue %",
        'cposition'=>"% $searchValue %",
        'fiverr'=>"% $searchValue %",
        'upwork'=>"% $searchValue %",
        'linkedin'=>"% $searchValue %",
        'profile'=> "% $searchValue %"
   );
}
 $query = " SELECT COUNT(*) AS `allcount` FROM `summary` ";
$STH =$this->DBH->prepare($query);
$STH->execute();
$STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$records = $STH->fetch();
$totalRecords = $records->allcount;

$srQuery = " SELECT COUNT(*) AS `allcount` FROM `summary` WHERE 1 ".$searchQuery;
$STH =$this->DBH->prepare($srQuery);
$STH->execute($searchArray);
$STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$records = $STH->fetch();
$filter = $records->allcount;

$orderQuery = " SELECT * FROM `summary` WHERE 1".$searchQuery." ORDER BY  ".$columnName."  ".$columnSortOrder." LIMIT :limit , :offset " ;
$STH =$this->DBH->prepare($orderQuery );


foreach($searchArray as $key=>$search){
   $STH->bindValue(':'.$key, $search,PDO::PARAM_STR);
}

$STH->bindValue(':limit',(int)$row, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$STH->bindValue(':offset',(int)$rowperpage, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$STH->execute();
 $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$empRecords = $STH->fetchAll();
$data = array();
foreach($empRecords as $row){ 
    $btn = '<div class="btn-group btn-group-sm ">
     <button type="button" name="update" id="'.$row->id.'" class="btn btn-info btn-xs btn-outline-info update" ><i class="fas fa-2x"></i></button> 
    <button type="button" name="delete" id ="'.$row->id.'" class="btn btn-secondary btn-xs btn-outline-secondary delete" ><i class="fas fa-2x"></i></button> 
     <button type="button" name="view"  id="'.$row->id.'" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs btn-outline-primary view" ><i class="far fa-2x"></i></button> 
     <button type="button" name="recover"  id="'.$row->id.'" class="btn btn-success btn-xs btn-outline-success recover" ><i class="fas fa-2x"></i></button> 
    </div>';
    
    $img = '';
    $profileImage = $row->profile;
    
if( $profileImage!== ''){
    $img = '<img src="images/'.$profileImage.'" class="img-fluid" alt="img"/> ';
}else{
    $img = '';
}

   $expertise =  $row->expertise;
 $exp = explode(",", $expertise);
 $des = new Format();
 $vision = $row->vision;
 $shortText = $des->textShorten($vision , 20);
 $data[] = array(
      "name"=> $row->name,
      "title"=> $row->title,
      "vision"=>$shortText,
      "expertise"=>'<a href="#" class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">'.implode(" ",$exp).'</a>',
      "experience"=> $row->experience,
      "cposition"=> $row->cposition,
      "fiverr"=> $row->fiverr,
      "upwork"=> $row->upwork,
      "linkedin"=> $row->linkedin,
      "profile"=> $img,
      "#"=> $btn
   );
}

$response = array(
   "draw" => intval($draw),
   "iTotalRecords" => $totalRecords,
   "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $filter ,
   "aaData" => $data
);
echo json_encode($response);        
        }

        //get records for editing in the modal

        public function getRecords(){
            if($this->id){
                $query = "SELECT * FROM `summary` WHERE `id`=:id";
                $STH = $this->DBH->prepare($query);
                $STH->bindParam(":",$this->id); 
                $STH->execute(array(
                    ":id" =>$this->id)
                );                
                $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                $row = $STH->fetchAll();
                echo json_encode($row);
            }
        }

        // view single data in front-end
        public function view()
        {
  $sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM summary WHERE `id`= '.$this->id.'";
  $STH = $this->DBH->query($sqlQuery);
  $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
  $singleData = $STH->fetch();
                
        return $singleData;
      }

      //update records in a modal
public function update()
        {
            $name = $this->name;
            $title = $this->title;
            $vision = $this->vision;
            $cPosition = $this->cPosition;
            $expertise = $this->expertise;
            $experience = $this->experience;
            $fiVer = $this->fiVer;
            $upWork = $this->upWork;
            $linkedIn = $this->linkedIn;
            $image = $this->image;
            if($THIS->id){
            $sqlQuery = "UPDATE summary SET
             name=?,
             title=?,
             vision=?,
             cposition=?,
             expertise=?,
             experience=?,
             fiverr=?,
             upwork=?,
             linkedin=?,
             profile=? 
             WHERE id='.$this->id.'";

            $dataArray = array(
                $name,
                $title,
                $vision,
                $cPosition,
                $expertise,
                $experience,
                $fiVer,
                $upWork,
                $linkedIn,
                $image
            );

            $STH = $this->DBH->prepare($sqlQuery);
            $result = $STH->execute($dataArray);

            if (!isset($name,
             $title,
              $vision, 
              $cPosition,
               $expertise, 
               $experience,
                $fiVer,
                 $upWork,
                  $linkedIn,
                   $image)) {
                echo "<p class='alert alert-warning text-center'>Filed Must not be empty</p>";

            } else {

                if ($result) {
                    echo '<p class="alert alert-success text-center">profile Updated Successfully!!</p>';
                } else {
                    echo '<p class="alert alert-info text-center">There was an error while Updating your Profile please try later!</p>';
                }
            }

        }
        }
          
    }
```

This is my table.js code:

```
// Data table processing
  $(document).ready(function(){

 var dataRecords = $('#example').DataTable({  
   bProcessing: true,
    serverSide:true,
  responsive:true,
  serverMethod: "post",
pagingType : "full_numbers",
//scrollX :true,
iDisplayLength: 8,
 alengthMenu: [ [10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"] ], 
ajax: {
    url: "fetch.php",
    type: "POST",          
    dataType:"json"
},

columns:[
{data: "name"},
{data: "title"},
{data: "vision"},
{data: "expertise"},
{data: "experience"},
{data: "cposition"},
{data: "fiverr"},
{data: "upwork"},
{data: "linkedin"},
{data: "profile"},
{data: "#"}
],

columnDefs:[
{targets: 10,
  orderable: false,
  searchable : false
}
]

});

  // page load on click

    $('.navbar').on('click','.nav-link',function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  var page = $(this).attr('href');
  if(page !=='#') {
 $.ajax({
 url: page,
 type: 'GET',
 dataType: 'html',
 success: function(data){

   $('#content').html(data);
   $('.navbar').height('auto');
   dataRecords.ajax.reload();
     }
    });
  
 } else{
    $(document.body).load('index.php');          
  }

    });



 //submitting form with ajax request

 $("#summary").on('submit',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var form = new FormData(this);
  $.ajax({
      url: 'sunForm.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: form, 
      async:false,
      dataType: 'json',            
      success: function(response) {         
              $('#message').fadeIn(800).html( response ); 
              $('#message').fadeOut(800).html( response ); 
              dataRecords.ajax.reload()
               }, 
     
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      cache: false
  });

  $('#summary')[0].reset();
; 

  return false;


  });  

  //this is code for showing single data from data table in a modal for 
editing

$("#example").on('click', '.update', function(){
  var id = $(this).attr("id");
  var action = 'getRecords';
  $.ajax({
   url:'action.php',
method:"POST",
data:{id:id, action:action},
dataType:"json",
success:function(data){
  $('#recordModal').modal('show');
  $('#id').val(JSON.stringify(data.id));
  //$("#user_img").val(data.image);
  $('#user_name').val(JSON.stringify(data.Name));
  $('#user_title').val(data.Title);
  $('#vision').val(data.Vision);                
  $('#expt').val(data.Expertise); 
  $('#exper').val(data.Experience); 
  $('#cPos').val(data.cPosition);   
  $('#fiver').val(data.Fiverr);
  $('#linked').val(data.linkedIn);
  $('#upwo').val(data.upWork);
  $('#action').val('update');
 // $('#save').val('Save');
    }
  })
});

  });
```